# I would like to bake a material into a texture

Tags: materials, uv

I have a model in which I want the material output to become a UV texture. How would I go about this?[image]

[image]

Comment: It should be possible to bake diffuse color as it is connected from Mix node to Diffuse shader. After that use the baked texture according to the UV map created for the mesh.

Answer (score -2):

I decided to use substance painter instead. Thanks for the help anyway. :)
[image]